How to add custom request headers in Blazor NavigationManager.NavigateTo
I have a Blazor Server Assembly in .NET 8, and I would like to redirect the browser to pages but add custom headers to the HTTP request the browser would make, in order to pass certain parameters that are not blatantly visible like on the query string.
Is there a way to do this?
I did find the exact same question asked 2 years ago with no answer (crickets chirping).

You can't do it in NavigationManager.NavigateTo.  It just raises an event that the router responds to.  In JS, I don't know.

That’s fair. In programming there are many ways to skin a cat - I am passing route and query string parameters, that will suffice. Is it fair to claim there is no way? My Googling has come up with naught.

There is no way. As an alternative to this, I would suggest the ways I am using to pass values:

Through a persisted (i.e. database) record
Using route parameters
Using query string parameters

With the latter 2, it is important to note that a period (.) in the passed data will result in a failed page request (I think a 404), so you should replace with a known character that is hardly used, e.g. a pipe (|), and replace back on the other end. Also, the values must be URL encoded (HttpUtility.UrlEncode()).
